# Mercurial plug in for Delphi

Tags: delphi, mercurial, delphi-xe

Is there a project or project in progress for creating a Mercurial plug in for Delphi XE?

Failing that, where can I learn more about creating one?

Comment: With Delphi XE8 there is now integrated support for Mercurial

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delphi XE has SVN support and the integration is an open source project, you can get it's code from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/radstudioverins/)

I read somewhere that they made it generic so it's not tied for SVN, but they add the SVN support because it's more popular and as starting point.

also as [Uwe Schuster](http://www.bitcommander.de/blog/index.php/2010/10/13/verins-intro/) blog (who developed the version insight for Delphi XE), both Git or Mercurial support are planned.

> Q: Will there be support for Git or
>   Mercurial? A: Support for both is
>   planned and first tests have been done
>   in the past months, but I don’t have a
>   timeframe. (Remember I do have a full
>   time job, work on Version Insight in
>   my free time and it’s not the only
>   thing)

Comment: VersionInsight Plus, which you linked, now supports Mercurial and Git fully.